# Isomorphism from inner direct product to external how to prove the following:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-sum

Let $$\phi_1:G_1 \to G_3$$ $$\phi_2:G_2 \to G_4$$ be isomophisms where $G_1 , G_2,G_3$ and $G_4$ are all groups.

How can I prove that $$\phi:G_1\oplus G_2 \to G_3 \oplus G_4  $$ is an isomorphism where $$\phi(x,y)=(\phi_1(x),\phi_2(y))$$ where $ x\in G_1, y \in G_2$.

Note that $(x,y) = (z,w)$.

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$.

Comment: You call three different maps by the same name; I'd advise against this. What are $x_1,y_2$ in the definition? What does the remark $(x,y)=(z,w)$ mean?

Comment: I have edited your question (to make it sensible and true) - if this is not what you are trying to ask just unroll the revisions.

Comment: yes it is thanks

Comment: Good. So is $\phi$ a homomorphism? Is $\phi$ $1-1$? Is $\phi$ onto? Which of these can't you prove?

Comment: onto is a bit rough

Comment: both i have operation preserving @ancientmathematician

Comment: Onto: given $(z,w)\in G_3\oplus G_4$ we know (because $\phi_1$ is onto) that there is an $x\in G_1$ such that $\phi_1(x)=z$, and similarly that there is a $y\in G_2$ with $\phi_2(y)=w$; then $\phi(x,y)=\dots=(z,w)$.